Supervisor does not want me to do my own research
This is a bit of an unusual problem, I feel, but I am conducting a PhD at a university, where it technically is possible to graduate without any first author publications. So my supervisor wants me to do that. I work on his project and have done all of the analysis for him. He is the first author. I am also doing another project for him and one for his colleague. I also have a project of my own that he wants me to drop.
I have done 20+ interviews and collected plenty of other data, written many versions and edited endlessly. Some of the effort that I have put in would warrant more than just second author, but it is what we agreed. However, he wants me to do a phd based solely on second and third author publications. I do not want to do that. I aim high and want my own publications. I have a lot of ideas, but he says it is not smart for me to pursue them. We have a conflict of interests, it seems. He sees me as cheap labor and career boost. I see myself as my own person and want to do my phd and my research on my own terms. How to solve this problem?

which country/cultural area?

Maybe you can be patient hang on to complete your PhD (if you are close to complete it) and continue your projects during pos-doc?

I am in Europe, don't want to specify which country

@Friendlyrobot222 Well, the cultural normals are pretty different throughout Europe. Can you perhaps add if you are paid by funds that are "owned" by your supervisor (e.g., third-party funded grant running under the name of your supervisor)?

Yes, I am. I also have my own funding under my own name, but most of the funding is third-party funding with supervisor as PI.

Is there a postdoc or someone else that you could pursue your own ideas with? You don't necessarily need to share details of your side projects with your professor.

Have you actually seen people graduating this way? "Technically possible" and "happening" have somewhat different meaning.

@tevemadar I have seen people graduate without any publications, having written a monograph. I know that in other faculties, there is a demand for an author of a compilation thesis to have at least one first authored article, but not in my faculty. But no, I have never seen anyone graduate with a compilation thesis without any first authored articles. Yet, this is what my supervisor demands while stating that he has my best interest at heart.

Here is the thing: this kind of behavior is normal, especially in some countries (Some institutions in Poland comes to mind here). Technically, during a PhD, he should be directing your research up to a certain point. So if you are at the beginning of PhD, i see nothing unusual. You (and the community) also have to stop with this thing about publications. If you get one out of your PhD is fine. No one cares about authorship order for a PhD publication, and is not unusual (in some countries) for a PhD to be awarded with no published papers.

I don't think that it is up to me as a phd researcher to stop the obsession with publications. It is the metric by which the academic world measures success. Also, many journals state that if the work is based on a student's thesis, the student should be the first author. He wants to publish first and see if I can get a phd out of it. What if the strategy is unsuccessful? I don't think I am being unreasonable in my point of view.

If your goal in the PhD is to move on to an academic career, this arrangement is not suitable for you. If your advisor is not supportive of your career goals, they are not suitable for you, either. If you cannot resolve this disagreement with your advisor, you need to find a different one. It's possible there is some other way you can compel your advisor to see things your way, like bringing in the influence of your graduate program or a department chair who could tell them that they're mistreating their students and behaving selfishly, but I think that's a rather short-term fix even if successful (you'd still be stuck in an advisory relationship with someone not interested in your best interests) and if their attitude is shared in the department the likelihood of even that modest success is low.
There are lots of existing Q&A here about changing advisors and changing PhD programs, so I'd suggest starting with a search here for more guidance on that, as well as familiarizing yourself with rules in your program.
In my own field and country, this conflict is solved rather simply by giving senior authors credit for being last author. A professor who has no senior (last) author positions because they're stealing all the first authorships of their students would stand out and not in a good way. In other places, unfortunately there are procedures that rate professors for their first author papers primarily (for hiring, promotions, even direct bonuses). If you are in one of those places, it's possible you will not find a better solution because the system is fundamentally broken.

Thank you for the comment. My supervisor has tenure, so I don't really understand why he acts this way. But I think you're right on the system being fundamentally broken.

@Friendlyrobot222 I don't usually think of Europe as one of the places where this specific behavior is highly incentivized by the system, but perhaps it is for your specific country. India is the example that comes to mind most strongly. If there are no other incentives past tenure then I think your odds are good that another supervisor in your country would be more reasonable.

This really sucks and I'm sorry to hear about your situation. As far as I see, the problem is twofold:

If you're employed via his grant, technically the work you have to do is pre-specified in the corresponding proposal. Many PIs are fairly relaxed about this and expect funders to be happy as long as you produce publications vaguely related to the topic. But other PIs aren't and you can't do much about that. If pursuing your own ideas is a high priority, the best way is to have PhD funding of your own, like a scholarship.


The authorship issue is independent of that. In my field, it would be highly unusual for the PI to be first author rather than last, esp if you did the bulk of the work (which it sounds like and is also typically the case). Under these circumstances the behaviour of your supervisor would be considered at least borderline unethical, I think. And bizarre - I don't understand what he gains from it, other than ruining your career, and flagging to future PhDs that he's not a PI you want to work with.

Now, how to deal with this? Bryan Krause gave an excellent answer, I think. I would add that the following sequence of actions seem advisable to me:
->  gather as much information about your options as you can (e.g. if switching supervisors is possible; if your university has a student advisory office or similar, use it)
-> rank your options by preference (e.g. whether you'd rather start from scratch with someone else / not pursue a PhD / pull through in case your supervisor is hell-bent on the current course)
-> prepare for a conversation in which you communicate these clearly to your supervisor (ideally, this could involve a role play rehearsal with an external coach; some student / postdoc offices offer to pay for something like this)
-> have that conversation
-> now you really know your options and can chose according to preference

Pursuing my own ideas isn't a high priority, but first author publications are. As I won't have them working in this project, I am forced to come up with my own ideas. I have been able to write a few article drafts (on my own data) working on my own grant, so there's that. Thank you for your comment and advise.

I agree that funding can constrain the work that is done and I think this is reasonable. It is not reasonable, though, for the professor to demand first authorship. They need to carve their grant into projects that can be completed primarily by their student, that's what it means to train a researcher to research.

@Friendlyrobot222 - first authorship often indicates that some of the ideas are the first authors own. If you are happy to conduct the work to merely collect and analyse data to support the ideas of your supervisor the question might be whether your project suffices for a PhD. As PBee says: gather information, and I would add, look for what requirements a PhD in your university has regarding showing independency in research.

I disagree with some of the above sentiments that you are an employee of the university. Most PhD students in the US where I am at are not considered employees here and do not give us the same benefits received by postdocs or any other employees like admin. The stipend you receive is significantly less than what you make as an employed research assistant not working toward a PhD (often called technicians).
When you are a technician, you are getting paid to do the experiments you're PI tells you to do. Some PIs give their technical staff more or less liberty to independently troubleshoot and pursue research objectives on their own. When you are a student, you get paid less, and the reason you get paid less is that part of your "payment" comes in the form of greater mentorship to become an independent scientist. This involves being given substantial independence in how you pursue overarching research objectives. It involves being given the time and freedom to fail and learn from your mistakes. While this freedom does have to be constrained so as to be justifiable by the grant you are being paid by, often from your PI's grant in the US life sciences, it is commonly understood by both granting agencies and PIs that in order to produce the next generation of independent scientists, you must allow some degree of freedom in choosing their research objectives with feedback and guidance from the PI.
If you are just doing the experiments your PI says, you aren't getting training that is the essence of the PhD: Being able to A) Identify a scientific problem worthy of investigation and B) solving that problem or some aspects of it. I've seen this happen with some students and even postdocs and I think it is really shortchanging these trainees because they are usually working much beyond a 40 hour week and getting chump change compared to what many people can make without a bachelor's degree.
My PhD advisor was a great mentor. His philosophy was to give his students "just enough rope that they don't hang themselves" lol.
I suppose the first author part of this varies by academic field, but in the hard sciences it would be unacceptable to not have a project you're working on that is expected to result in the student getting first authorship. I also agree with what others said that in biomedical sciences, the PI very rarely gets a first authorship, as they take the last author spot. This is the norm. Occasionally a PI will have first author if written primarily based on his own work in collaboration with other faculty level scientists.
My opinion is that students need to be mentored, not trained, and guided, not given directions. You need to develop your sense of intellectual independence and your confidence in it. I would say all departments should have a student oversight committee that should be able to speak with you confidentially and help in handling the dispute, whether by giving you advice on handling it yourself or mediating the conflict directly.
I hope you get your situation resolved. Don't be afraid to boldly advocate for your own interests. After all, that's why you are pursuing a PhD!

A PhD student being a employee is simplly a matter of legal fact in most of Europe. Particularly in northern europe, PhD students are mostly employed, with contracts of employement, and due all the same rights and benefits as any other employee. Usually this employment is via a PIs grant, where the PI will have had to pre-specify what work will be done in order to get the grant.

Sir,
You have missed the point. Universities are run by human beings. Departments are the same. You are a student but you are also an employee, and by tradition you are an apprentice. A research university is a a place you work at to generate unique and groundbreaking ideas. You exist for the University. It does not exist for you. The University serves the public. Now, I am not saying that you shouldn't do the research you want to do. Keep it going, if it's about getting your magnum opus out there and read, 10 years is not a long time to wait to arrive at its content falling under a lot of eyes.
Now, do you think you can get your work in a top 4 article in field? Unless you are someone along the likes of John Nash, I doubt it. What your advisor is doing making you. You should feel honored.  Yes it his research, but he is offering you citations that you could otherwise never get on your own. Then, 10 years from now, when you have 4 A pubs, you can submit this idea to a top journal with a high probability of acceptance.
Remember, human beings are very much human beings regardless of the costume. Learning how to navigate is as important as the the amazing findings that the world needs you to share with it.
This of course just my opinion. Ask others ( that are successful) and see what they say.

This may be field specific, but first author publications in your PhD are the empirical norm and expected in e.g. neuroscience. And yes, these papers can land high impact journals.

I think you share my advisor's views, but not mine. He also believes I have slim chances of publishing in a quality journal, but all of the important discoveries in his paper are mine, so if I have slim chances, so does he. I haven't shown him my own research, so the evaluation is not based on facts.
